# Node js Express Error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

Everything worked just fine until all of a sudden this error occurred: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I had no luck in figuring it out on my own so please help me if you can.

I use express-handlebars and express to route my pages and I thing I saw where the problem occurres. In my bookController file when I use res.**render**('something') no matter from what route it always redirects me to '/' and when I use res.**send**('something') It redirects to where it defined.

This is my app.js file:

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const hbs = require("express-handlebars");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const routes = require("./routes/index");
const expressValidator = require("express-validator");
const errorHandlers = require("./handlers/errorHandlers");

const app = express();

const webpack = require("webpack");
const webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config.js");
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
const webpackDevMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware")(
  compiler,
  webpackConfig.devServer
);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware);
app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.engine(
  "hbs",
  hbs({
    extname: "hbs",
    defaultLayout: "main",
    layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views/layouts",
    partialsDir: __dirname + "/views/partials"
  })
);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(flash());

app.use(
  session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: process.env.SECRET
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(expressValidator());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.flashes = req.flash();
  next();
});

app.use("/", routes);

app.use(errorHandlers.flashValidationErrors);

module.exports = app;
```

This is my index.js file

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const bookController = require("../controllers/bookController");

const { catchErrors } = require("../handlers/errorHandlers");

router.get("/", bookController.home);

router.post("/contact", catchErrors(bookController.contactForm));

router.post("/productPage", catchErrors(bookController.productForm));

module.exports = router;
```

This is my bookController file:

```js
const mail = require("../handlers/mail");

exports.home = async (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
};

exports.contactForm = async (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const subject = req.body.subject;
  const text = req.body.text;

  await mail.send({ email, subject, text });
  res.redirect("/");
};

exports.productForm = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  res.redirect("/");
};
```

I will very appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: can you try by putting `return res.render("index");` ?

Comment: I tried but it did not work. Shows the same error in the browser. Only when I write send instead of render it works.

Comment: Does the res.render return an error? You can check by passing Callback to it, ```res.render('index', function(err, html) {

if (err) console.error(err);
  res.send(html);
});```

Comment: You sir are awesome. I did what you say and it showed mw this error: {
message: "Must pass iterator to #each",
name: "Error"
} I had an each loop in my view. The thing is that it was commented out. For some reason it is not possible to comment out hbs code in the view ? Now I erased it and it works. Thank you

Comment: The problem was commeting out the hbs code in the view using normal html comment: <!-- --> This does not work. USE {{!-- --}} to cimment hbs code in the view.

Comment: Great, if res.render returns an error it triggers next() automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Answer which solved the question.

If `res.render()` does not stop the request (Same way as `res.send(html)`), usually means there is error in the render function. As the behaviour of `res.render()` is that if it errors, it will trigger `next(err)`.

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render

> When an error occurs, the method invokes next(err) internally.

Errors are quite simple to be tracked in the function, by passing an callback into the render;

```
res.render('index', function(err, html) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  res.send(html);
});
```

Once you can trace the error and fix it, problem should be solved.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed to do to see the problem. I did not know that I needed to do that. THANKS !