# My website has an error of redirected too many times (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: node.js, cpanel

So I have a problem which show that when i want to enter /info it keeps on redirecting between /info and /info/ and cause ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (this page isnt't working and redirected yoo too many times). And for the development, I am using node.js and express with the source code looks like this

```
app.get('/info', (req, res) => {
            res.render('info', {
            layout: 'layouts/layout',
            title: 'Info',
            user: req.session.user,
        });
})
```

Also the website is hosted on cpanel (for reference).

I have tried to fixed the bug by changing the '/info' into '/info/' but the website still showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `res.render()` is generating an error and then triggering `next(err)`?  If so, add in error catching to resolve. Like this answer:
[Node js Express Error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605453/node-js-express-error-err-too-many-redirects)